# formik form validation with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using formic form library to my form. I need to validate my textbox. This is my validation file

```
    import * as Yup from "yup";
const POValidation = Yup.object().shape({
  tax: Yup.number().typeError("Amount is invalid")
});
export { POValidation };
```

this is my texbox

```
<Form.Control
          type="text"
          size="sm"
          placeholder=""
          name="tax"
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          value={values.tax}
          className={errors.tax && touched.tax && "input-error"}
        />
```

currently it allowed only number. but letters can enter. i need to avoid entering letters in this texbox. how i do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup has a `matches` method that allows checking over a regex.

```
Yup.string().matches(/^[0-9]+$/, "Only number allowed")
```

The first parameter of the method is the regex, the second parameter is the error message thrown at regex failure.

Comment: I tried your solution. but error ..
TypeError: yup__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.number(...).matches is not a function

Comment: Do you have the latest versions of Formik and Yup in your package.json?

Comment: Yup.string().matches(/^[0-9]+$/, "Only number allowed")   when i change number to string, its working ..